# Stop the execution of a background thread iOS

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

In an iOS app (objective C), I am creating a background thread in this manner:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
//doing some lengthy task here
});
```

At some point of time (if a condition satisfies) I want to cancel the execution of the above mentioned thread. How can I do it?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use then an NSOperation (check [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/))

You'll have to create a subclass of NSOperation and put your login inside the "main" method. Then, when you want to use it, just create an instance of your subclass and launch it.

And, if you want to cancel it, just call the "cancel" method.